# Why cannot Hive Map key (i16) cast upside when search by key?

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-query

There is Hive table that is defined by thrift.

```
struct A {
    1: optional map<i16, string> myMap;
}
```

I have tried a few queries to search through this table.

```
// this one gets an error:
select myMap[10] from A where myMap[10] is not null
```

> Line 1:74 MAP key type does not match index expression type '10'

And the following two returns the right results.

```
// this one works well
select myMap[10S] from A where myMap[10S] is not null

// this one works well
select myMap[10Y] from A where myMap[10Y] is not null
```

I know `10Y` means `tinyint` and `10S` means `smallint`, and `i16` is `smallint`.

But why does Hive cast a `smallint` to `tinyint` instead of `int`?

I think this may cause some information loss or number overflow.